# Store Multiple image URLs in a single row in database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, normalization

I need to store multiple images in a row. So, I can follow two approches.

**1. First Way**

One approach is 1NF form (which should be avoided as I have read in books).

I will create a table **Feed** with a column url and store several URLs separated by a Comma

**id** **url**

1  a.jpg,b.jpg,c.jpg

2 xyz.jpg,image.jpg

To retrieve images, I would use explode()

```
  $photos = explode(' , ', $url);
```

**2. Second way**

The second way is to normalize the table and create a separate image table with a Many to One relationship with table Feed

Feed table:

**id**

1

2

Image table:

**fid** **url**

1 a.jpg

1 b.jpg

1 c.jpg

I want to know why we should avoid the first approach? or is it ok to use first approach for just small projects?

Comment: What if you want to sort on the image url. With 1NF it will make it very complex to do at database level. With normalized form it will be simple ORDER BY clause. It also applies to WHERE clause as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have a variable number of image names?  "Arrays" should be implemented as rows in another table.  As with your #2.

You have obviously done your homework and read the arguments; I will not rehash them here.  Instead, I suggest turning the question with two learning exercises.

1. Go ahead and implement #1.  A month from now you will understand the issues.  At that point, you will get to learn another lesson, namely ...
2. how to change a schema (1 table into 2) and preserve the data.  It will take a few SQL statements; they will be the second learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about images normalization will not bring you anything. You never filter, sort or aggregate by images' filenames.

So, your initial idea is close to correct (First way). But I would advise using json_* functions to store the values.

```
$urls = json_encode( ['x.jpg', 'y.jpg', 'z.jpg'] );
// INSERT INTO mytable (..., urls) VALUES (..., $urls);

// SELECT urls FROM mytable;
$photos = json_decode($data['urls']);
```